# Run SonarLint in Connected mode when SonarQube requires smart card authentication

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, cac

I am attempting to run SonarLint in connected mode. I've created a token but I continue to get "Fail to request https://sonar/.../api/system.status". If I copy that link and paste it into my browser the link works fine.

SonarQube: 6.3
SonarLint: 3.2.0
Eclipse 4.7

I do have the proxy setup in Eclipse, which works when I connect to the Eclipse Marketplace. Also I do require a smart card to access the SonarQube server. I'm thinking that is the issue, but I do not know the way forward with this.

I have attempted to look through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Config but I cannot make any sense out of it or how to make it work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem you did.

To get past my reverse proxy, I had to add a security provider in jre/security/lib/java.security. To use it with Eclipse, I added the necessary system properties to eclipse.ini.

I documented the solution in the SonarQube group at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarlint/-FXcPeh_kw0/evkZgL8GCwAJ

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a smartcard to access SonarQube, there is an authentication system in front of SonarQube, so the authentication with token (SonarQube internal authentication mechanism) through SonarLint won't work.

I don't see a workaround for this situation.